# How to place 4 figures side by side in latex

Tags: floats

I want to place 4 figures side by side in latex such that two are in row one and other are in row 2. I have written the following code, but not getting it correctly.

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/combinedMLED8ns_new.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{MLEDdet}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/ML_ED_PSK.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{energydetPSK}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Vel6ns.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{velcomp}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidthh}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/est4ns.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{estcomp}
\end{minipage}
\caption{}
\label{fig:roc}
\end{figure}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Correcting `\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidthh}` with class `article`  the code works fine. See [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxh0D.jpg

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(edited the answer after coming to understand that what the OP wants is to have four *subfigures*, arranged within a 2x2 pattern, within a single `figure` environments)

Obviously, you have to start by fixing the typo in `\linewidthh`. Next, if your objective is to have four separate "subfigures" within an overall `figure` environment, you should load the `subcaption` package and replace all 8 instances of `{minipage}` with `{subfigure}`. (A `subfigure` environment is, for all intents and purposes, a `minipage` environment that's been taught what to do if and when it encounters a `\caption` directive.)

You may also want to (a) get rid of all five `\centering` instructions (since they do nothing useful), (b) maximize the horizontal separation between the subfigure pairs 1/2 and 3/4, (c) increase the vertical separation between the rows of graphs via a `\bigskip` or `\medskip` directive and, optionally, (d) increase the `minipage` widths from `.45\linewidth` to `.475\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]

\begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/combinedMLED8ns_new.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{MLEDdet}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- "\hfill"
\begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/ML_ED_PSK.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{energydetPSK}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip % create some *vertical* separation between the graphs
\begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/Vel6ns.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{velcomp}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- "\hfill"
\begin{subfigure}{.475\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/est4ns.eps}
  \caption{}
  \label{estcomp}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with four subfigures}
\label{fig:roc}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to subfigures \ref{energydetPSK} and 
\ref{estcomp} of figure \ref{fig:roc}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your highly useful code and answers......

Comment: @Saru - I've revised my answer to take into account that you (probably ) want to display four subfigures within a "main" `figure` while still being able to create cross-references to individual subfigures (as well as, of course, the main figure).

Comment: Sir... Thank you very much for the detailed code....

Comment: @Mico, do you know by any chance how to get rid of the small (a), (b), (c) and (d) in your example ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Gigi - Just get rid of the `\caption` statements in each `subfigure` environment. While you're at it, get rid of the associated `\label` statements as well. Finally, replace all instances of `{subfigure}` with `{minipage}`. (A `subfigure` environment is, basically, a `minipage` environment that knows what to do when it encounters `\caption` directives. Since you don't want captions, you might as well use `minipage` environments directly.)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, I do need a caption. I would like to have the caption without the numbering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gigi - I suggest using `\caption*` directives to create unnumbered, you guessed it, captions.

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this code as the example:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{r1}
\label{qwe1}
\end{center} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{r1}
\label{qwe1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\vspace{0.2 cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{r1}
\label{qwe1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{r1}
\label{qwe1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Correlation}
\label{ris}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: @ anton how can we use label here....

Comment: The only valid optional positioning/alignment arguments for a `minipage` are `t` (top), `c` (center, which is the default), and `b` (bottom). The option `h` is not recognized and is simply ignored. Also, `\center{...} a)` is *awful* coding practice. Please don't do it. Instead, do please write` \centering\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a} a)`.

Comment: @Saru I have made some edits for You (as I understand You correctly)

Comment: @ Mico Sir, understood.....Once again thank you....

Comment: @Anton sir.... thank you for your answer...